# How to pass bound variables to a subcomponent?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue component which calls another component, passing some props:

```
<template>
  <div id="weather">
      <weather-part class="night" from="0" to="8" data="data"></weather-part>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import weatherPart from "./weatherPart.vue"
export default {
    name: 'weather',
    components: {
        "weather-part": weatherPart
    },
    data() {
        return {
            data: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        // the place where this.data is actually initialized
    }
}
</script>
```

The problem is that what is passed to the `data` prop is the string `"data"` (as checked with the Vue addon to Dev Tools).

**How can I pass the value of `this.data` instead?** (probably as a serialized string)